# Images for next/prev navigation for a blog

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I am trying to get the next/prev links at the bottom of my blog to show up with just images. I have the positioning and the links set up correctly with the images that I want to use as well. The problem is though that the links are only working on the text that I used from the original code. I have the image that I want to use set up as the background of the div. I can not figure out how to make the image a link and delete the text.

Link to blog:

http://www.conutant.org/test-box/

What is have inside my PHP:

```
<div id="bottomnavigation">
    <?php if($single) { ?>
        <div class="nextprev">
            <span class="prev"><?php previous_post('&lsaquo;&lsaquo;&lsaquo; %', 'PREVIOUS TUTORIAL', 'no', 'no'); ?></span>

            <a href="http://www.conutant.org"><div id="homeicon"></div></a>

            <span class="next"><?php next_post('% &rsaquo;&rsaquo;&rsaquo;', 'NEXT TUTORIAL', 'no', 'no'); ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.nextprev {
    height: 100px;
}

.nextprev .prev {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width:200px;
    background: url(http://www.conutant.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Prev.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    margin-left: 19px;
}

.nextprev .next {
     float: right;
     height: 100px;
     width:186px;
     background: url(http://www.conutant.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/next.png);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: left top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with :

```
<div id="bottomnavigation">

<?php if($single) { ?>
<div class="nextprev">
<span class="prev"><img src="http://www.conutant.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Prev.png" alt="<?php previous_post('&lsaquo;&lsaquo;&lsaquo; %', 'PREVIOUS TUTORIAL', 'no', 'no'); ?>" /></span>
<a href="http://www.conutant.org"><div id="homeicon"></div></a>
<span class="next"><img src="http://www.conutant.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/next.png" alt="<?php next_post('% &rsaquo;&rsaquo;&rsaquo;', 'NEXT TUTORIAL', 'no', 'no'); ?>"</span>
</div>
<?php } ?>


</div>
```

You don't need background in your css anymore

Answer (score 1):

Apply the background image to the anchors, not to the spans.

```
.prev a {
 float: left;
 background: url(http://www.conutant.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Prev.png);
}

.next a {
 float: right;
 background: url(http://www.conutant.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/next.png);
}
```

You also need to set the anchors as block elements:

```
.prev a,
.next a {
 display:block;
}
```

And finally use `text-indent: -9999px` in order to hide text.